# Generating an alpha mask from a texture

Tags: c#, xna, alpha

I am trying to create a function in one of my helper classes that will take a texture (left) and then generate an alpha mask (right)

[image]
[image: mask]

Here's what I have so far:

```
public Texture2D CreateAlphaMask(Texture2D texture)
{
    if (texture == null)
        return null;
    {
        RenderTarget2D target = new RenderTarget2D(Device, texture.Width, texture.Height);

        Device.SetRenderTarget(target);
        Device.Clear(Color.Black);

        using (SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch(Device))
        {
            BlendState blendState = new BlendState()
            {
                AlphaBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Max,
                AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.One,
                AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.One,

                ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add,
                ColorSourceBlend = Blend.InverseDestinationColor,
                ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.Zero,

                BlendFactor = Color.White,
                ColorWriteChannels = ColorWriteChannels.All
            };

            batch.Begin(0, blendState);
            batch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            batch.End();
        }

        Device.SetRenderTarget(null);
        return target;
    }
}
```

What should be happening is that if alpha=0, then the pixel is black, and if alpha=1, then the pixel is white (and interpolated between these values if needed).

However, I can't seem to make it go "whiter" than the base image on the left. That is, if I set it to blend white, then *at most* it will go to the grey tones that I have, but never brighter. This isn't something I can create in advance, either, as it must be calculated during the game.

Comment: do I understand correctly, you want to set the color channels r,g,b to the source alpha value and the alpha to 1?

Comment: I *think* so. I only have a vague idea of how to work with the BlendState, and less of an idea to get a specific effect out of it.

Comment: To me it seems that a shader would be more suitable, as you completely ignore the blend target. You want to transform the source image into something else.

Comment: You probably get more response for stuff like this at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/